# Stream HTML audio in background WP7 app

Tags: html, windows-phone-7, audio, background

I am trying to figure out some way to stream HTML audio I have in a WebBrowser control in the background/when my app is closed.
Does anyone have any experience with this, success or failure?

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Not possible directly from a WebBrowser, you'll have to use a BackgroundAudioTask and capture the stream directly

Comment: That's the part in trying to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends on the way you have your streaming infrastructure you use. Some websites, like Pandora, have a pretty good implementation for that.

You can start [here](http://html5doctor.com/native-audio-in-the-browser/) to see how to use the HTML5 `<audio>` tag, if that is what you intend to use.